# HTTP post header is incorrect

Tags: javascript, node.js, http, post, httprequest

I am using node.js to send HTTP POST to an APP server. The email address joe@gmail.com in POST body shows up as joe%40gmail.com on APP server side. I used Content-Type text/plain in the following code but application/x-www-form-urlencoded is actually in the POST request header, according to the server log.

My earlier post has a mistake on Chrome postman results. Please ignore it, and sorry for the confusion.

I am new to this, and may have missed something obvious here. Any help is appreciated.

Here is the code:

```
var express = require("express");
var app = module.exports = express();
var request = require('request');
var config = require('../config'); 
app.post('/', function(req, res) {

    var username = req.body.name;
    var password = req.body.passwd;
    var email = req.body.email;
    console.log("email=", email);

    // connect to APP server
    var url = config.appServer;

    request( {
        uri: url,
        method: "POST",
        timeout: 10000, // 10 sec
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'text/plain'
        },
        form: {
            act: 'create',
            username : username,
            passwd: password,
            email: email
        }
        }, function (error, response, body) {
            // handle return here
```

Comment: Looks like it's url-encoded, did you try just `decodeURIComponent()` it ?

Comment: Looks like it's an issue with your other app, not this one, since the `console.log` outputs the right string. Update the question with the code of the `/account` post handler

Comment: No, I haven't tried decodeURIComponent(). I can use Chrome, safari to send HTTP GET request with the same string. They all show up correctly on APP server side. I probably missed something in the header of node.js request, but don't know what.

Comment: gfpacheco & adeneo, Thank you for your comments. Given the content-type x-www-form-urlencoded, the above results are understandable. The remaining question is why the header is incorrect from the code above. I've  corrected a mistake on postman in the earlier question.

Answer (score 0):

That's completely normal behavior. Also you don't need to set the `content-type` header when using the `form` option with `request`.

Here is a short example:

```
request({
  uri: 'http://requestb.in/1g2xzno1',
  method: 'POST',
  timeout: 10000, // 10 sec
  form: {
    act: 'create',
    username : 'username',
    passwd: 'password',
    email: 'joe@gmail.com'
  }
  }, function (err, res, body) {
    if (err) console.log(err)
    console.log(body)
  })
```

You can see the results from that request [here](http://requestb.in/1g2xzno1?inspect). This is what your app server receives. Then all you need to do is parse the request body on your app server (it's the string below the RAW BODY header):

```
var qs = require('qs')
qs.parse('act=create&username=username&passwd=password&email=joe%40gmail.com')

{ act: 'create',
  username: 'username',
  passwd: 'password',
  email: 'joe@gmail.com' }
```

Alternatively if you are using Express on your app server you can use the `body-parser` middleware that will do the same for you:

```
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}))
```

Comment: Simo, Thank you for the explanation. I also tried to replace "form" with "json" in the above code, and then I can set header to application/json. It works now.

Comment: Accept the answer if it works for you. That way the answer will be sorted out as answered.